# Saving entity with one-to-many relations with spring-data-jdbc returns empty list

Tags: java, relationship, optimistic-locking, spring-data-jdbc

I have an issue with the return value after saving an item (`ArticleList`) with one-to-many relations(`ArticleListEntry`) in Spring Data JDBC. When creating an entity for the first time, upon calling `repository.save(entity)` my return entity, including all related items, are saved correctly in the database. However, the returned value contains an empty list for `entries`. The fields on the original `ArticleList` are always filled correctly.

I have the following entities:

```
@Table("article_list_meta")
@Data
public class ArticleList {
    @Id
    private final Long id;
    @Version
    private long version;
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "list_id", keyColumn = "seq")
    private List<ArticleListEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();  
    
    @PersistenceConstructor
    public ArticleList(Long id, String publication, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.publication = publication;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public ArticleList(String publication, String name) {
        this(null, publication, name);
    }
    // other fields
}
```

and

```
@Data
@Table("article_list_entry")
public class ArticleListEntry {

    @Column("article_id")
    private final long articleId;

}
```

With a repository

```
@Repository
public interface ArticleListRepository extends CrudRepository<ArticleList, Long> {}
```

I persist it using

```
        ArticleList entity = repository.findByPublicationAndName(publication, name)
                .orElseGet(() -> new ArticleList(publication, name));
        entity = mapper.fromDto(entity, list, fieldsToUpdate);
        ArticleList persistedEntity = repository.save(entity);
```

After the initial (`version == 0`) save, all following updates do include all related items.
Note that an `AbstractRelationalEventListener<ArticleList>` receives the same entity-with-empty-list for the first call to `save(articleList)` (`persistedEntity`). The `entity` still contains the articles.

This leads me to believe I stumbled upon a bug, but since this is our first project using data-jdbc instead of data-jpa, there might also be something wrong in my entities.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.6.RELEASE with version 2.0.5.RELEASE of spring-data-jdbc.

Comment: Do you have setters for the fields? does making the fields package private (no modifier) solve the issue? How do you set the id or expect Spring Data JDBC to set it?

Comment: I see that I've cleaned up my posted code a little too much, the collection has a `@AccessType(AccessType.Type.FIELD)` annotation on it, because I have disabled getters/setters for them to shield the `ArticleListEntry` datatype outside the aggregate. They are correctly filled when accessing through a `findBy` method via the field accessor, but apparently for saving it isn't. Adding public setters and setting the accessType to `Type.PROPERTY` gives the same result - a `find` method invokes them, `save` doesn't. Changing the field to package protected also doesn't change anything.

Comment: In fact, when setting a breakpoint in `BasicJdbcConverter#populateProperties`, I notice that it gets hit when performing an update, but doesn't when doing the insert. Digging a little deeper, I notice that it only gets hit because I do a `findBy` before `save`, so the difference is not the insert/update per se.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. You didn't answer this one though: How do you set the id or expect Spring Data JDBC to set it?

Comment: Sorry, missed that question. I have a `@PersistenceConstructor public ArticleList(Long id, String publication, String name) `, I'll update the code in my question

Comment: That does indeed look like a bug. Could you create an issue, complete with a reproducer? https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAJDBC

Comment: Related issue: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJDBC-647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an effect of `entries` not being part of the persistence constructor.

When a constructor is used to create a copy of an instance (e.g. because the id needs to be set), only the properties included in that constructor get copied over.

So in order to fix the problem you should modify the constructor of `ArticleList` to look like this:

```
@PersistenceConstructor
public ArticleList(Long id, String publication, String name, List<ArticleListEntry> entries) {
    this.id = id;
    this.publication = publication;
    this.name = name;
    this.entries = entries;
}
```